# Laravel 5.3 upload image from url and get image data

Tags: php, image, laravel, url, upload

I am trying to upload youtube thumbnail image locally and get their data like file size and so on. From links like this one: http://img.youtube.com/vi/bnRVheEpJG4/maxresdefault.jpg
I am getting url from oembed like this:

```
$info = Oembed::get($externalMedia);
$image = file_get_contents($info->image);

dd($image->getClientOriginalName());
```

I just want to save the image to the server, but before that I would like to check if the youtube maxresdefault thumbnail exists. So I was thinking of checking the image size first, so that if it is low, I don't upload it, since that is not a maxresdefault thumbnail then. Not sure of any other way of achieving this.
But I don't get any image uploaded to the server, I guess base64 data or not sure what is this:

```
����JFIF``��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 90
��C




��C     

��h�"�� 
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?����(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��Q�(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(�b�
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(���1F(��(��(��(��(��(��o�V:���������~j�Ǔ=�����(����?�&��K��=�뤟�ZQ~Ϟ �����e��T��W�]|׬�������_�5Y��+ա��3�����
�h�R��g�k?�ot��]d���T���$�����e��T�W���_��ޝ�%��URO�:�=n������y��K��Q����Y��[��������Ew_���o��c��*[_�Z�����/����t���R�ڽ�K��<[�K��q�����J?��t�����/?��:�����#_fϞh�����'��=K�V�������5�X�/�)jG0�����]/����9�٢����N�]����?�u�ȵn�$o�ٿ�d�G���-2O����b��=�e���<��_�%[�����n�(��/���>   ȣ"����1�i����?�}�ȕ�7���$_fx������D�as�
�_J|p��<�HmO_Դ�D��Εu,�?��(�������1�4T�C�K��T`у^����z�G�k�a���%�����1�x�i�������:߄���]]�-m���\��}��o���<C������Z��7���1�#�������C/i��إ�}��{���C'���:���*���H����/���>���k?���ޟs���Q�}������C��>���k*��   {�GM�]������ju(T��i��tW���O���ּ/��W?�f�����q]cÇ�ޥ��U�j|�E}�S�y�j���/��?���q�A��T��j�>y��������|7��7?�f���|@��b������3@3�_Y��7>%j?�u�    �����"��_�J����������Z����[�;�w����u��"ո���f�����u�ȴ��O��Wݱ��2M�Ğ�o�����Ø�4�������JF^�ρ����J�����������}��"Tr��~4ę>%��_��%0���|�6���P��C�`�����߅���"��t�ſ�|���_��Rޟs�}�������I�[����?�u�ȴã�/���������Z���|E�����:7���^  �����E���{��/��}��"ӹ��)�>�F�������_�}��"՘�����L�x��}�Ȕ�)�>�����_Ҿ���;�d������}�ȴÞ>2���O����Z�F/�a������*5����K��Tڅ��kRu^��Z�a��xO�<!���"���6�M&�-R��[�ֵ/��
��T���xWɰ�o
```

How can I upload image and get it's data with php/laravel?

Comment: That is because you doumping the image. Store the image in your web storage and access it by its path. You are halfway there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just `echo` an image like you would do with some text, you have to inform the browser that you are giving him an image so he will know how to deal with it.

Also, when you do a `file_get_contents`, you get the raw data as a string so you can't call `$image->getClientOriginalName()`

What you have to do is send a header to the browser with the image type and then echo the image data.

```
// get the media
$info = Oembed::get($externalMedia);
$image = file_get_contents($info->image);

$imageInfo = getimagesizefromstring($image);
$width = $imageInfo[0];
$height = $imageInfo[1];

if ($width > 100 && $height > 100) {
    // save image to file
    file_put_contents($newfilename, $image)
}

// send to the browser
return response($image, 200)->header('Content-Type', $imageInfo['mime']);
```

[`getimagesizefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns the width, height and mime type from a binary string

Comment: But I would like to do that before uploading anything, how can I do that?

Comment: @Leff you just want to save the file from the url ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to save the image to the server, but before that I would like to check if the youtube maxresult thumbnail exists. So I was thinking of checking the image size first, so that if it is low, I don't upload it, since that is  not a maxresult thumbnail then. Not sure of any other way of achieving this

Comment: when I tried using your code I got Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Articles\finfo' not found

Comment: see my edit, it does not use finfo anymore. finfo needs to be activated in the php.ini http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: thanks, how can I then save it to the server, because now I get: Undefined variable: newfilename

Comment: you just have to replace `$newfilename` with whatever you want for the name of the saved file

Comment: ah, ok, I thought I would be saving the image to the server, not base64 data, didn't read your answer properly. So, there is no way of actually creating and saving the image to the server like it would be done if it was uploaded from form, and not just saving it like base64 data from url?

Comment: the file IS saved, when you do `file_put_content`, a new file is created with the image grabbed from the `$externalMedia` url

Comment: yes, but it was saved as base64 data, not as image to show like I would have if I was to upload an image from form

Comment: It was missing extension, that's why it was showing as raw data, when I added extension it showed as an image: file_put_contents(public_path($this->destinationPath.'/'.$articleId.'.jpg'), $image);